# Photos and Camera usage on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, photo-stream

I am constantly being warned that my 32GB iPhone is running low on free space. Looking at Usage in Settings I can see that 10.5GB are being used by Photos & Camera, with the breakdown:
Photo Library: 9.2 GB
Synced From iTunes: 137 KB
My Photo Stream: 1.1 GB
Shared Photo Stream: 227 MB

My Camera Roll in the Photos app only has 5 pictures. My Recently Deleted album has 85 photos. I am trying to determine where the rest of the storage is being used, and how to free it up.

My extended family and I use Shared Photo Streams to share pictures of our kids. On my iPhone I'm subscribed to seven Shared Photo Streams, the largest of which has 1,800 pictures and 100 videos (the rest are much smaller).

Is the Shared Photo Stream storage being lumped in with Photo Library in the usage breakdown? Or is something else going on?

[image: Photos & Camera Usage]

[image: Photo Albums]

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Settings > General > Date & Time Untoggle "Set Automatically"
- Manually set the date a year or two in the past
- Open "Photos"
- Select "Albums"

  If, like me, you had already cleared out everything from the
  Camera Roll and "Recently Deleted" folder, you'll smile to see that
  your "Recently Deleted" folder now has thousands of images back.
  Those are your phantom photos Open it, "Select" and start deleting
- Return to "Date & Time" and fix your clock

Now, go back into Settings > General > Usage > Storage > Manage Storage. You'll notice your Photo & Camera is empty if you deleted everything

Answer (score 0):

Clear your recently deleted folder. It is still using space on the phone. There may also be videos within the recently deleted that may be consuming the bulk of space.